# Unable to open website locally

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu, nginx

I am unable to open a website locally in my browser.

I am using ubuntu and my browser is Chromium(Version 39.0.2171.65 Ubuntu 14.04 (64-bit))

Web server is nginx

Whenever I open the website locally in office it opens just fine, however when I try to open the website at my home it displays below error message in console

```
GET http://mywebsitename.somedomain.com/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

I tried using below command for automatically setting the proxy settings

```
chromium-browser --proxy-auto-detect
```

but nothing has worked.

In firefox same thing happens.

Please help me if anyone has dealt with this issue.

Comment: Are other sites open normally?

Comment: Yes other websites are opening fine over internet. The issue is with website that I am running locally.

Comment: Provide us your webserver logs, in this case nginx error.log and access.log latest entries.